# Angular router-outlet in children component not showing anything

Tags: angular, routes

app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
{
path: 'app',
component: MainLayoutComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'travels',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/travels/travels.module').then(m => m.TravelsModule),
  },
],
```

},

**main-layout.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

MainLayoutComponent is loaded correctly, because if I write "console.log("TEST") it is printed correctly in the console but the children component not loaded.

**travel-.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { TravelsRoutingModule } from './travels-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/shared/shared.module';

import { TravelsListComponent } from './travels-list/travels-list.component';

const SHARED_COMPONENTS = [TravelsListComponent];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...SHARED_COMPONENTS],
  imports: [TravelsRoutingModule, SharedModule],
})
export class TravelsModule {}
```

**travel-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { TravelsListComponent } from './travels-list/travels-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TravelsListComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class TravelsRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Can you recreate in a stackblitz?

Comment: and what is demo module?

Comment: @KurtHamilton I have update the post

Comment: @AleandroCoppola It's good to show the relevant code, but a live recreation of your problem would be really helpful. It might also help you realise what the problem is while you're setting it up. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with what you've posted.

Comment: @AleandroCoppola And silly question - I assume you're testing with the url `/app/travels`?

Comment: @KurtHamilton Yes, and the MainLayoutComponent works because if I write in ngOnInit() {console.log ("TEST")} it works correctly.
But not load nothing into <router-outlet>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

PROBLEM:
***MainLayoutComponent*** is declared into **SharedModule** and not in AppModule.

But in SharedModule not imported **RouterModule**

Answer (score 1):

Things worth checking (sorry if they're obvious):

1. Is main-layout.component.html imported correctly inside MainLayoutComponent?
2. Are there any errors in the browser console which could be preventing things from loading correctly?
3. Is the lazy load module being downloaded in the browser network tab?
4. If you create the child route as a standard route & not a lazy loaded module does it work?